# How do delegates work in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates

I'm trying to figure out delegates because I really need them for a project I'm working on, but for the life of me, I can't figure them out. No matter how much I tweak the code, nothing works

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@protocol testDelegate
-(void)sayHi;
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController 

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic)id <testDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DelegateController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
DelegateController *dc = [[DelegateController alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
[self.delegate sayHi];
}
@end
```

DelegateController.h:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface DelegateController : UIViewController <testDelegate>

@end
```

DelegateController.m:

```
#import "DelegateController.h"

@interface DelegateController ()

@end

@implementation DelegateController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"init");
        ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        [vc setDelegate:self];
}
    return self;
}
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)sayHi
{
    NSLog(@"hi");
}


@end
```

The - (IBAction)button:(id)sender method is connect to a button, but when clicked I get no output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check this tutorial
http://enroyed.com/ios/delegation-pattern-in-objective-c-and-writing-custom-delegates/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

#### ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@protocol testDelegate
-(void)sayHi;
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController 

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic)id <testDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

#### ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DelegateController.h"


@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) DelegateController *dc;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  _dc = [[DelegateController alloc] init];
  [self setDelegate:_dc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender
{
   [self.delegate sayHi];
}
@end
```

#### DelegateController.h

```
@interface DelegateController : UIViewController <testDelegate>

@end
```

#### DelegateController.m

```
#import "DelegateController.h"

@interface DelegateController ()

@end

@implementation DelegateController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        NSLog(@"init");
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)sayHi
{
    NSLog(@"hi");
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks! So basically what I was doing wrong was that in ViewController.m, dc needed to be an ivar?

Comment: @user2314004: because you are using the delegate call from another method and you are assigning it to a weak pointer. So I prefer dc should be a private ivar

Comment: What's the point of using a delegate at all if ViewController is creating DelegateViewController? You could just call a method in DelegateViewController since you have a pointer to it. The delegating class isn't supposed to know what class its delegate is, that's why the delegate is declared as id. It seems to me that this approach is the reverse of the usual delegation pattern where the delegate creates (or otherwise gets a reference to) an instance of the delegating object.

Answer (score 1):

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol testDelegate
    -(void)sayHi;
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController 

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DelegateController.h"

@interface ViewController () <testDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)pushNewViewController:(id)sender
{
    DelegateController *dc = [[DelegateController alloc] init];
    dc.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dc animated:YES];
}

- (void)sayHi
{
    NSLog(@"It works!");
}
@end
```

DelegateController.h:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface DelegateController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<testDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

DelegateController.m:

```
#import "DelegateController.h"

@implementation DelegateController

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender
{
    if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sayHi)]) {
        [_delegate performSelector:@selector(sayHi)];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that ViewController creates DelegateController, then in DelegateController you're creating a new, different, instance of ViewController, and setting yourself as the delegate of that instance. Normally, the way you set a delegate is that DelegateController would create an instance of ViewController and set itself as the delegate. This assumes that DelegateController is created first, but exactly how to do this depends on your app structure, and how you move from controller to controller.

Answer (score 0):

Replace you button Click method with following

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    // Check whether your Delegate method is implemeted or not
    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sayHi)])
    {
        // Call Delegate Method
        [delegate performSelector:@selector(sayHi)];
    }
}
```